# How to show products dynamically based on visitors' geolocations on WooCommerce store?

Tags: wordpress, location

I would like to display WooCommerce products, categories based on visitors' locations. For example if someone from **"New York, US"** is visiting the website then it'll show New York-specific product to them instead of showing all products from the store.

If someone visit from **"Indore, India"** then it'll show specific product which I would like to sell to that specific area. So, based on visitors' GEO locations it'll show the products accordingly.

I don't have any specific IP list but I would like to display products based on locations.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: please explain more about your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try this https://www.templatemonster.com/help/woocommerce-how-to-display-single-and-multiple-products-by-id-or-sku.html

Comment: I want to show some products for only Indore location

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail or share URL?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding [WooCommerce Geolocation Based Products](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-geolocation-based-products/)

This WooCommerce plugin/extension that adds ability for your store to show/hide products based on visitors geolocation.

You can add many different countries in which you want the settings to apply to. You do this by adding a rule and setting the 2 letter ISO country code in which you want to apply to. For example “US”. You then can set which products and categories to show/hide. You may select more than one for each rule.

You can also add a region or filter by city.

Comment: Do you want to serve based on the zip code or based on GEO Location? What is the end result you're looking for? It depends upon what you want to serve to the customer.